# Django POST issues in views

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I'm trying to allow a user to update a Boolean variable of a model, but I seem to be having trouble saving the change to the db and then rendering the change to the template. the model is 'Pic' and the boolean variable is 'Good'.

In the template (namespaced 'single_picture'):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if Pic.Good %}
    <input type="submit" name="choice" id="{{ Pic.id }}" value="False" />
    {% else %}
    <input type="submit" name="choice" id="{{ Pic.id }}" value="True" />
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

In urls of the app:

```
url(r'^(?P<Pic_id>\d+)/$', views.single_picture, name='single_picture'),
```

and in views.py:

```
def single_picture(request, Pic_id):
# 'detail' in tutorial
if request.method == 'GET':
    pic = get_object_or_404(Pic, pk=Pic_id)
    latest_pictures_list = Pic.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'pictures/single_picture.html', {'Pic': pic, 'latest_pictures_list': latest_pictures_list})
elif request.method == 'POST':
    pic = get_object_or_404(Pic, pk=Pic_id)
    latest_pictures_list = Pic.objects.all()
    try:
        pic.Good=request.POST['choice']
    except (KeyError, Pic.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'pictures/single_picture.html', {'Pic': pic, 'error_message': 'uhhhh...',
        })
    else:
        pic.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pictures:pic', pic.id))
```

If I print pic.Good to the terminal at the end of the try: statement I can see it's showing the changed one, but pic.save() doesn't seem to save it to the db, and I also get

ImproperlyConfigured at /pictures/4/

The included urlconf 4 doesn't have any patterns in it

at the render statement. That seems to point to something missing in the project or app's urls. How to save the changes correctly and render the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to django [documentation on reverse function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/), the second parameter is urlconf argument.

> The urlconf argument is the URLconf module containing the url patterns to use for reversing.

To supply parameter for url construction you need to use *args* or *kwargs* named arguments.

Try changing your return statement to something like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pictures:pic', args=[pic.id]))
```

I don't know about database save problem, but try to move your pic save call closer to pic update code for debugging purpose:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    pic = get_object_or_404(Pic, pk=Pic_id)
    latest_pictures_list = Pic.objects.all()
    try:
        pic.Good=request.POST['choice']
        pic.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pictures:pic', args=[pic.id]))
    except (KeyError, Pic.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'pictures/single_picture.html', {'Pic': pic,     'error_message': 'uhhhh...',
        })
```

**Edit 1**

Regarding NoReverseMatch error, you are using [url namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) ('pictures:pic'). I'm not very familiar with it, but i guess that the *reverse* function looks for view with *name='pic'* inside the url configuration for *pictures* app.

Are you sure, that such view exists in your url config file?

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve either of my issues. The changes still aren't being saved to the database, and I'm getting

NoReverseMatch at /pictures/4/

Reverse for 'pic' with arguments '(4,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

errors for the reverse() call.

Comment: Could you please post all your url configuration for app? Or at least configuration for 'pictures:pic' url?

Comment: Seems you were right. I updated the return request to:

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pictures:single_picture', args=[Pic_id]))`

'single_picture' being the url name. I also had to update the arg to 'Pic_id'.

Answer (score -1):

not an answer to your question, but a good tip is to replace this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if Pic.Good %}
    <input type="submit" name="choice" id="{{ Pic.id }}" value="False" />
    {% else %}
    <input type="submit" name="choice" id="{{ Pic.id }}" value="True" />
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

with this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="choice" id="{{ Pic.id }}" value={% if Pic.Good %}"True"{% else %} "False" {% endif %} />
</form>
```